Why is $E[f(X)|X]=f(X)?$
I am taking "random signals and noise" course, and the professor said that $E[f(X)|X]=f(X)$.
I tried to prove it, even for the simpler case $E[X|X]=X$, but I did not succeed. I found the answer given in How can I show that the conditional expectation $E(X\mid X)=X$?, but I did not understand it, so I opened this one.
I have not studied measure theory so I do not know Borel sets, probability as measure, etc. So, I tried to think of the following, but this does not feel good enough:
For the discrete case, we have $E[X \mid X = x'] = \sum_{x} x \frac{P(X=x, X = x')}{P(X = x')}$. If $X\not=x'$, then $P(X=x, X = x')=0$, and if it does, then $P(X=x, X = x') = P(X=x)$ and the sum is just on the element with x ($x=x'$), so $\sum_{x} x \frac{P(X=x, X = x')}{P(X = x')}=x'$.
I am not sure how to generalize it to the case where we have $f(X)$ instead of $X$, and to the continuous case.
I would appreciate any assistance.

What definition of the conditional expectation are you using?  It seems like you don't have the right understanding that would make the equation clear.

I am using $E[g(X)\mid Y = y] = \sum_{x} g(x) \frac{P(X=x, Y = y)}{P(Y=y)}$ for the discrete case and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \left( \frac{f_{X,Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} \right) , dx$ for the contiuous case.

Your argument in the discrete case works with $g(x)$ also. Work it out before we move on.

@KurtG. $E[g(X) \mid X = x'] = \sum_{x} g(x) \frac{P((X = x, X = x')}{P(X = x')}=g(x') \frac{P(X = x')}{P(X = x')}=g(x')$ where i used the same argument above in the second equality?

I can follow and it is correct but who knows what your second equality was. Now think about the continuous case. With this approach you might run into difficulties because for $X=Y$ the joint distribution is degenerate. The correct way of answering your title question is by going right to the measure theoretic definition of the conditional expectation. Case closed.

@KurtG. Thank you, so what gaps should I close in measure theory before being able to answer my question?

You should learn about $\sigma$-algebras and measurable functions. It is total standard and can be found in zillions of textbooks in a fairly early chapter.

Let $g \left( X \right) = E \left[ f \left( X \right) \mid X \right]$.
Since $g \left( X \right)$ is the MMSE Estimator of $f \left( X \right)$ given $X$ it obeys the Orthogonality Principle:
$$ E \left[ \left( g \left( X \right) - f \left( X \right) \right) h \left( X \right) \right] = 0, \; \forall h \left( X \right) $$
Specifically for the case $h \left( X \right) = f \left( X \right)$ which yields:
$$ E \left[ g \left( X \right) f \left( X \right) \right] = E \left[ f \left( X \right) f \left( X \right) \right] $$
Which implies $g \left( X \right) = f \left( X \right)$ as the optimal estimator.

Toda raba ;) much appreciated.

The conditional expectation $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$ is the unique random variable $Z$ of the form $g(X)$ for some function $g$ with the property that $\mathbb E((X-Z)^2)$ is minimized. If $Y$ is already a function of $X$, then clearly it is its  own conditional expectation.
